# CASE STATEMENT SUPPORT

Tags: sql

Can I refer to my previous CASE statement? I know the code is wrong but I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT
Distinct(trafficSource.campaign) AS Campaign,

Case 
  When (SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,10,4)) = 'news' then  'eNEWS'
  When (SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,23,4)) = 'news' then  'eNEWS'
  Else Null
End as **eNEWS_Flag**,

Case
  When **eNEWS_Flag** = 'eNEWS' then (SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,21,2)) Lang_Flag,

From Blah Blah 

WHERE eNEWS_Flag is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,(c)`

Answer (score 1):

Given the current `WHERE` clause, which eliminates all rows where the proposed `eNEWS_Flag` expression returns `NULL`, you should be able to refactor this without using any `CASE` expressions at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  trafficSource.campaign AS Campaign,
  'eNEWS' as eNEWS_Flag,
  SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,21,2)) AS Lang_Flag,
From Blah Blah 
WHERE
  SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,10,4) = 'news'
  OR
  SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,23,4) = 'news'
```

But you can't reference the column alias of an expression within the same `SELECT` clause in most (any?) SQL dialects. Nor in the `WHERE` clause, since most engines evaluate the `WHERE` clause before they evaluate the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You must either repeat the conditions or nest this `SELECT` inside another.